# SQL Query to find distinct records and update the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ABC which has following records -

```
   INVC_NUM    | LINE_NUMBER  |  ORGANIZATION_ID  | STATUS    |  DATE

   0000034454       1             521                 Validated   09/09/2016 

   0000034454       2             521                 Validated    04/09/2016 

   0000034410       1             521                 Validated    04/09/2016

   0000034410       2             521                 notValidated    04/09/2016

    0000034410       3             521                 notValidated   04/09/2016

    0000034410       4             521                 Validated   04/09/2016
```

Now I need to update a table XYZ which has following columns

```
  INVC_NUM     |   ORGANIZATION_ID   | date

  0000034454   |   521               | 09/09/2016    
  0000034410   |   521               | null
```

Whenever the status for all the Line_number's for particular INVC_NUM and organization_id are "ALL" validated(status)then we need to update XYZ with max(DATE) FOR that INVC_NUM.

Whenever the status for all the Line_number's for particular INVC_NUM and organization_id are NOT ALL of them validated(Status) then we need to update XYZ with NULL. XYZ has unique record for each INVC_NUM and Org_id.

Comment: update xyz
set date =
case when not exists
  (
    select *
    from abc
    where abc.invc_num = xyz.invc_num
      and abc.organization_id = xyz.organization_id
      and abc.status = 'notValidated'
  ) then sysdate 
end;  -- This Query posted by Gordon updates the date with sysdate and I need to update with max date.

Comment: Is the status `not null` in all cases? Are `Validated` and `notValidated` the only possible values?

Answer (score 0):

This should work to update the completely validated `organized_id/invc_num` combinations with their max date, otherwise `NULL`:

```
UPDATE XYZ
SET DATE = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM ABC
                                 WHERE ABC.ORGANIZATION_ID  = XYZ.ORGANIZATION_ID 
                                 AND ABC.INVC_NUM = XYZ.INVC_NUM
                                 AND ABC.Status = 'notValidated') 
                THEN (SELECT MAX(DATE)
                      FROM ABC
                      WHERE ABC.ORGANIZATION_ID = XYZ.ORGANIZATION_ID 
                      AND ABC.INVC_NUM = XYZ.INVC_NUM) 
                ELSE NULL
                END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update with a `MERGE` statement. Most of the work is done in the aggregation subquery in the `USING` clause. I changed the date column name from `date` to `dt` - don't use Oracle keywords as column names.

```
merge into xyz
  using (
          select   invc_num, organization_id, 
                   case when max(case when status = 'Validated'
                                      then dt else date '9999-12-31' end)
                             = date '9999-12-31'
                        then null
                        else max(dt) end as dt
          from     abc
          group by invc_num, organization_id
        ) g
       on (xyz.invc_num = g.invc_num and xyz.organization_id = g.organization_id)
when matched then update
  set xyz.dt = g.dt
;
```